# Excel: Replace Number Format in Diagram

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have an Excel Workbook which will be sent to a client and I need to get the thousands and decimal seperators right.
I have a Workbook.Open routine which will change to custom formatting (and back on close)

```
.UseSystemSeparators = False
.DecimalSeparator = ","
.ThousandsSeparator = "."
```

I also have a bunch of charts, which seem unaffected by this change. How do I convince Excel to display charts with a custom decimal separator?

My approach so far was to use number formatting, but I cannot figure out how to actually REPLACE a separator, instead of displaying it. Is there a way to use . (period) and , (comma) to locate the thousands-separator, but at the same time ommitting to print it?

Is there an alternative Way of forcing chart axis to use the above-mentioned application settings for separators?

Thanks.